Deleting lines added with another macro while retaining totals row and formulas
I have an expense form that I have built that has a header section and then a table for expense entries.  The table starts with 15 rows available for entries and a 4th row that is the total(s) row all of the rows have an amount column and reimbursement column at end of each row.
I built an "Add New Line" button tied to a macro that adds new lines as the user may need more.
I have a "Reset Form" button that is meant to clear all header information and delete any new lines in the table returning the table to the original 15 empty lines plus the totals row.
The clear piece of the "Reset Form" Button works great but I can't get the delete piece to work.  The macro is below, help with this will be greatly appreciated.
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim clearRange As Range
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim fixedRow As Long
    Dim extraRows As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Expense Report")

    Set clearRange = ws.Range("B15,B16,B17,B18,C4,C7,C15,C16,C17,C18,D15,D16,D17,D18,E15,E16,E17,E18,F15,F16,F17,F18,G15,G16,G17,G18")

    clearRange.ClearContents

    fixedRow = 15

    ' Define the row for totals
    totalsRow = 30
    
    ' Find the last row in the sheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    If lastRow > fixedRow And lastRow >= totalsRow Then
        ws.Rows(fixedRow + 14 & ":" & totalsRow - 3).Delete
    End If
    
    MsgBox "Form has been reset!", vbInformation
End Sub

I've tried multiple different versions to get the rows deleted leaving the Totals Row and formulas in the Reimbursement column.  The current version listed above does fine but reduces the rows to 13 not to the original 15

Is it just totalsrow to last row you need to delete, fixedrow+14=totals row, is that coincidence?  not sure without seeing the sheet.

Can you clarify what 4th row for Total(s) mean?

Still really needs a screenshot....

ws.Rows(fixedRow + 14 & ":" & totalsRow - 3).Delete deletes rows 27 to 29 regardless of what  the last row is. Maybe you meant ws.Rows(fixedRow + 14 & ":" & LastRow - 3).Delete. Also if lastRow >= totalsRow then it must also be > fixedRow

Set clearRange = ws.Range("C4,C7,B15:G18") It's not at all clear how your code can leave formulas in the Reimbursement column when your code deletes entire rows...
